# How can I get rid of the reference of the object?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I store my state with React hook management. When I CRUD Operation something like this

```
const {state} = useContext(myContext);

const CRUD = async () => {
   state.entity.id = generateId();
   state.entity.name = "bla bla";
   state.entity.status = true;
   .... POSTING PROCCESS       

}
```

After that the operation, It changed the state without reducer. I don't understand, I don't want to changing.

I tried some examples to fix this problem but it didn't work.

```
let clone = {...state.entity}; // not work
var copy = Object.assign({}, state.entity); // not work
const other = {...state.entity}; // not work
//.....or other same thing not work. (const, var, let combination)
```

Comment: you can always do "deep" copy by using
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)); But note that it will delete (as it can't create json) functions or other components. So if you have something like state.entity.myFunc = function() = { } ... then it will be lost. Or If you have state.entity.myCustomEditor = <Editor /> then it will be lost too.

Comment: But i would say it should work with just a shallow copy like {...state.entity}

Comment: How did the lines at the end "not work"? Those all look good to me, assuming you want to create a copy before modifying it and sending it over to a server, all without modifying state.entity.

Comment: @Aaron I'd say the same.

Comment: Thx, my object is stored only entity something nested arrays or object, not store any component or function :) well Is that the only true way ? @emsiiggy

Comment: @CoderDeneme there are libraries to do deep copy to not lose anything. As you don't have anything special in there, then it should be enough. If you could provide live demo (or steps to recreate the error) then it would be much better for us to look at this.

Comment: I dont understand why didnt not work :) when i change entity properties without reducer, It state changes @emsiiggy

Comment: Reducer? so you're probably using redux. I'm not familiar with it, so won't be able to help with that...

Comment: No, I'm using react hooks without redux @emsiiggy

Comment: Show us live demo please. You can do it in https://stackblitz.com/ for free. Or codesandbox

Comment: It so hard to demo, I have 240 component in my app and I got lost in it :) Thank you for your helping. @emsiiggy

Comment: Okay, good luck then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator only creates a shallow clone of an object.

You could do this:

```
const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.entity))
```

This will copy your state but won't copy any object methods or prototypes within.

So, you should always use `setState()` when mutating state